# return issue for method

Tags: java, return

I am having an issue with a method returning to the main method. It is saying that amount in "return amount" cannot be resolved to a variable. Where am I off on this??

This is the message I get: 
Multiple markers at this line
    - Void methods cannot return a 
     value
    - amount cannot be resolved to a 
     variable

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Investment {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the amount invested: ");
        double amount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the annual interest rate: ");
        double interest = input.nextDouble();

        int years = 30;

        System.out.print(futureInvestmentValue(amount, interest, years)); //Enter output for table
    }

    public static double futureInvestmentValue(double amount, double interest, int years) {

        double monthlyInterest = interest/1200;
        double temp;
        double count = 1;

        while (count < years)
            temp = amount * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest,years *12));
        amount = temp;

        System.out.print((count + 1) + " " + temp);
    }

    {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to indent your code. Makes it easier to read.

Comment: you cannot return something from main method.remove the return and print some message or error.

Comment: Please add appropriate tags and indent your code.

Comment: What are you learning from???

Comment: You've made edits to your code that have confused your initial question.  At this point I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You curly braces are not correct. The compiler - and me - was confused about that.

This should work (at least syntactically):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Investment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the amount invested: ");
        double amount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the annual interest rate: ");
        double interest = input.nextDouble();

        int years = 30;

        System.out.print(futureInvestmentValue(amount, interest, years));
    }

    public static double futureInvestmentValue(
            double amount, double interest, int years) {

        double monthlyInterest = interest / 1200;
        double temp = 0;
        double count = 1;

        while (count < years)
            temp = amount * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, years * 12));
        amount = temp;

        System.out.print((count + 1) + " " + temp);

        return amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be declared in that block; the outer scope is visible.

Comment: No, I think you were right; I misread the original code--it wasn't inside the method at all.

Comment: Ok, so I have the curly braces as you have noted, but now it is telling me that temp has not been initialized. It notes this inside the while loop. I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: @user1019838: `temp` must be initialized (get an initial value) like `double temp = 0;` because it has no default value

Answer (score 0):

Remove `amount` from its own scope As a start. Also from the method `futureInvestmentValue`, you take in `amount` as an argument but the value is never modified so you're returning the same value being passed which is most likely not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `return amount` from its own scope
2. the method `futureInvestmentValue`... You can't modify any of the parameters inside the method so you have to declare another variable besides amount inside the method (maybe it's the `temp` variable you keep using) and return that instead
3. when you return something, the return statement is always inside the method. Never outside it while inside its own braces (never seen this before...)

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Investment {
       public static void main(String[]args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.print("Enter the amount invested: ");
           double amount = input.nextDouble();

           System.out.print("Enter the annual interest rate: ");
           double interest = input.nextDouble();

           int years = 30;

           System.out.print(futureInvestmentValue(amount, interest, years)); //Enter output for table
       }

       public static double futureInvestmentValue(double amount, double interest, int years) {

           double monthlyInterest = interest/1200;
           double temp;
           double count = 1;

           while (count < years) {
               temp = amount * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest,years *12));
               System.out.print((count + 1) + " " + temp);
           }

           return amount;
       }
   }
   ```